# Javascript: ColumnWidth & gutterWidth?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, widget

I have this js to handle the divs in my footer when resizing the screen. However I do not really understand the variables of ColumnWidth & gutterWidth. Could someone further elaborate on these? For some reason the settings below cause the right (last) div in the footer to have too much margin to the right when resizing. In other words the divs start reordering now when there is still a lot of margin left (when resizing the screen). Hope you understand, below is my code, thanks a lot!:

```
/**
     * Arranges footer widgets vertically.
     */
    if ( $.isFunction( $.fn.masonry ) ) {
        var columnWidth = body.is( '.site-footer' ) ? 228 : 245;

        $( 'ul.nav-menus' ).masonry( {
            itemSelector: 'li.custsub',
            columnWidth: columnWidth,
            gutterWidth: 20,
            isRTL: body.is( '.rtl' )
        } );
    }
```

Comment: You havent defined a container element!

Comment: What does that mean? How to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Checkout http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html for example. Its the element that wraps the columns.